# Pick random observation for each by group in SAS

Tags: random, sas

I have two datasets: *form* and *pool* having similar table structure.

a) Dataset ***form***
[image]

b) Dataset ***pool***
[image: pool dataset]

- The above two datsets have three columns where each ***Key*** and ***Level*** combination in ***form*** dataset have 4 rows.
- Also ***Sub-Level*** data in ***form*** and ***pool*** data is mutually exclusive at ***Key*** and ***Level*** level.
- ***Sub-Level*** values has a particular ***Level*** assigned to them i.e. ***Level*** and ***Sub-Level*** follows a hierarchy.

I want to populate the *null values* under ***Sub-Level*** column in ***form*** dataset with **Sub-Level** values in ***pool*** dataset where a ***Sub-Level*** in ***pool*** dataset shoud belong to same ***Key*** and ***Level*** of ***form*** dataset.

How can be this done in SAS ?

**EDIT 1** : *null values* that are populated in ***form*** dataset must be distinct or unique within each by group of ***key, level***.

Comment: Where does the randomness component, mentioned in both your title and tag, come in?

Comment: @superfluous: randomness comes into picture while selecting Sub_Level from "pool" dataset randomly, to populate null values in "Sub-Level" column in "form" table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new row ID in `form`: `key`, `level`, `new_id`.
2. Random sort `pool` on group level and create the same id.
3. Left join by `key`, `level`, `new_id` and replace missing values.

As there are less or equal values per group in `form` compared to `pool` and all values are disjunct and unique you will complete `form` without generating duplicates.

Code example:

```
data form;
  set form;
  retain new_id;
  if first.level then new_id = 0;
  new_id + 1;
run;
data pool;
  set pool;
  ran_num = ranuni(12345); /* generate random uniform number */
run;
proc sort data=pool; by key level ran_num; run; /* sort by random number */
data pool;
  set pool;
  retain new_id;
  if first.level then new_id = 0;
  new_id + 1;
run;
proc sql;
create table form_full as
  select a.key, a.level, coalescec(a.sub_level,b.sub_level) as sub_level
    from form a
      left join pool b
        on a.key eq b.key and a.level eq b.level and a.new_id eq b.new_id
      ;
quit;
```

edit: 
In case `pool` has fewer rows in a group than `form`,
change `new_id` in `form`:

```
data form;
  set form;
  retain new_id;
  if first.level then new_id = 0;
  if sub_level ne . then new_id + 1;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, for your reply, but I think my question earlier has missed out another constraint which I have included in "EDIT 1" of original question. Actually the replaced values must also be unique within each by group of "key" and "level". Will appreciate if you'd be able to help with that

Comment: I adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Jetzler : that helped !!